Maui application working with signalr service crashes when invoke method added
I create maui application and integrate with AspNetCore.signalr services. This app connected server succesfully and also invoke method on server. But when I added method which invoke by server on maui application app crashes automatically. I am unable to get error as application goes in break mode don't show any error message.
private async void btnSignIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl("https://mysite.bsite.net/chat")
             .Build();
   
    _connection.On<string>("broadcastMessage", (s2) => Getmsg(s2));

    try
    {
        await _connection.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Warning", ex.ToString(), "Ok");
    }
}
private async void Getmsg(string s)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Warning", s, "Ok");
}

How can I solve this error message. Please give me a solution Thanks In Advance.

add a try/catch in Getmsg

Sir I tried. Still method is not invoke.

if your app is crashing you need to wrap all of your code in try/catch blocks until you find the cause.  Or step through the code in the debugger

Does it help? Maui App after update Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client to 6.0.8 release build crash without error message

Are you trying to listen server method _connection.On<string>("broadcastMessage", (s2) => Getmsg(s2)); before the service started?

No sir. Before invoke method from server I confirmed that service is started with help of code:   private async void btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)     {         if (_connection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)         {             await DisplayAlert("Warning", "Running", "Ok");             //await _connection.InvokeAsync("Send", "mobile", "yes");         }         else         {             await DisplayAlert("Warning", "Stop", "Ok");         }     }
